# Calling overloaded methods from generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have a list of Foo and Bar objects, and a converter for each of the corresponding ones.

```
public static void Convert(Foo1 a, Bar1 b) {
...
}
public static void Convert(Foo2 a, Bar2 b) {
...
}
etc
```

Some of the objects, however, contains lists.
The Convert-methods needs to be different, because Bar1 is vastly different from Bar2 and Bar3 and so on, but I want to create one method to handle all possible lists.

Is it possible to create a generic method that calls the appropriate non-generic method depending on the contents of the list?

So far I've tried this:

```
public static <T, S> void ConvertList(List<T> list, List<S> libList) {
    list = new ArrayList<T>(libList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < libList.size(); ++i) {
        Convert(list.get(i), libList.get(i));
    }
}
```

But that doesn't compile because "Cannot resolve method 'Convert(T,S)'"

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried this as well

`Convert(list.get(i).getClass().cast(list.get(i)), libList.get(i).getClass().cast(libList.get(i)));`

but that didn't work either.

Comment: As an aside, it would be a good idea to start following Java naming conventions...

Comment: Yeah I know, I just mocked something together. Problem remains, though. I'd rather not write one 'convertList' method for each Foo-Bar  pair.

Comment: When you're "mocking something together" for the sake of a question, the fewer distractions you can put in front of those answering, the better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this - overloading is determined at *compile-time*, and it sounds like you want different methods to be called based on either the execution-time type of the objects involved, or at least on the execution-time type of `T`, which is completely unknown at execution time.

Code-path decisions based on execution-time type are usually handled via overriding via overloading, but it's not clear whether this is feasible in this case. If you could put an appropriate `convert` method in each `Foo??` subclass, you could potentially constrain `T` and `S` accordingly, but basically there's too much context we're unaware of at the moment.

You *could* use reflection to find and invoke the most appropriate method at execution time, but that's going to be painful to code and potentially significantly slower.

Comment: Thanks! So basically; create a `convertList(List<Foo1> a, List<Bar1> b)` for each set then? Or put the convert method in the Foo/Bar objects. Think I'll go for the last option.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use runtime polymorphism to achieve this.

Step 1: Create interfaces representing each type.

```
public  interface Foo<T> {
    public void convert(T bar);
}
public interface Bar<T> {
    public void convert(T foo);
}
```

Step 2: create implementation classes.

```
public class Foo1 implements Foo<Bar1> {

    @Override
    public void convert(Bar1 bar) {
        System.out.println("Foo1, Bar1");
    }
}
public public class Bar1 implements Bar<Foo1> {

    @Override
    public void convert(Foo1 foo) {
        System.out.println("Foo1, Bar1");
    }
}
public class Foo2 implements Foo<Bar2> {

    @Override
    public void convert(Bar2 bar) {
        System.out.println("Foo2, Bar2");
    }
}
public class Bar2 implements Bar<Foo2> {

    @Override
    public void convert(Foo2 foo) {
        System.out.println("Foo2, Bar2");
    }
}
```

Step 3: Create function which calls convert method according to instances in the list.

```
public static <T extends Foo, S extends Bar> void convertList(List<T> list,
        List<S> libList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < libList.size(); ++i) {
        list.get(i).convert(libList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Step 4: Create Sample list data and test it

```
    List<Foo<?>> listOfFoos = new ArrayList<Foo<?>>();
    List<Bar<?>> listOfBars = new ArrayList<Bar<?>>();
    listOfFoos.add(new Foo1());
    listOfFoos.add(new Foo2());
    listOfBars.add(new Bar1());
    listOfBars.add(new Bar2());
    convertList(listOfFoos,listOfBars);
```

Comment: That's still not going to compile unless there's a `Convert(Foo, Bar)` method, which certainly isn't specified in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks.Updated the answer.  I guess now you can remove down vote.

Comment: No, as this now doesn't satisfy the ability to pass in different lists of different types: "Is it possible to create a generic method that calls the appropriate non-generic method depending on the contents of the list?"

Comment: Yes, potentially - *if* there's only one Bar pairing for each Foo and *if* `Foo` can be modified. This is basically what I was suggesting in my answer, with "If you could put an appropriate convert method in each Foo?? subclass, you could potentially constrain T and S accordingly." That's the trouble; we really don't have enough information to give a "best" approach :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. Thanks a lot. I am really great Fan of you.

Comment: There is only one Bar pairing for each Foo, and both classes can be modified.